# Integrate bootstrap responsive design in .net shopping cart platform

Tags: .net, webforms, responsive-design

My team are in some problem with customer requirements that wants responsive design for his website. I found **bootstrap** http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html can do responsive design but my team don't know how to use it with shopping cart platform (vevocart) that my team used. This platform is base on .net Web form development model and I realize that when using shopping cart platform to create website all code with create automatically then it is to hard to integrate any lib for those code because it may cause some function will not working if I make false edit on some related code.

I wonder if it has another way to solve this problem or we should use simple way that create new entire of website by our coding not use shopping cart platform.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap as it is is just a simple css-js-grid framework, you just would have to add the js files and the css files and the adapt the HTML Source with the matching classes and attributes you wouldnt need any new C# libs for that, or do you mean by all code is generated that everything even the html is generated via c#? - then you would still only have the adapt the classes.

I advise you to build a prototype out of the rendnered page (adding the bootstrap layout to a saved rendnered site) and then integrate it into the code where the html is generated

let me know if you need any further help

regards jan

Comment: Yes everything is generate via shopping cart platform. Thank for your suggestion summery I think its remain one solution is modify html for compatible with bootstrap. Does anyone have new solution?